# Временная шкала на html

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать подобную шкалу времени на html с добавлением 'красных участков'

Была идея сделать для каждого часа свой прогресс бар. Для заполнения определять по часу прогресс бар и просто убирать час, а минуты использовать как проценты

На bootstrap получилось сделать что-то [подобное](https://jsfiddle.net/gzpof3j0/)(Закинул на jsfiddle, внутри SO не работает)

На сколько это 'правильная' реализация?

Шкала нужна для вывода планов на день

Есть таблица с планами, в ней есть столбцы `date_start` и `date_finish`

Дата храниться подобным образом `2018-11-09 10:00:00`

Выбираем желаемую дату и смотрим, что на эту дату запланировано. Простой вывод сделан(на скрине справа). На скрине шкала не подключена(Тестирую)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD ---

Во что у меня получилось:

Контроллер:

```
  $rez = Plan::whereDate('date_start', '>=', $plan_day)
                ->whereDate('date_start', '<=', $plan_day)
                ->get();//Достаем планы за определенное число
  foreach ($rez as $item) {
    $date_start_h = date("H", strtotime($item->date_start));
    $date_finish_m = date("i", strtotime($item->date_finish));
    if($date_start_h == 9) {
      $progress['nine'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 10) {
      $progress['ten'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 11) {
      $progress['eleven'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 12) {
      $progress['twelve'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 13) {
      $progress['thirteen'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 14) {
      $progress['fourteen'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 15) {
      $progress['fifteen'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 16) {
      $progress['sixteen'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    } else if($date_start_h == 17) {
      $progress['seventeen'][] = ($date_finish_m*100)/60;
    }
  }
  $v['progress'] = $progress;
  return $v;
```

Вывод (`planDay.progress` равен `$v['progress']` из контроллера):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="padding-right: 0;">
    <div>9:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="nine in planDay.progress.nine">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+nine+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>10:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="ten in planDay.progress.ten">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+ten+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>11:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="eleven in planDay.progress.eleven">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+eleven+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>12:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="twelve in planDay.progress.twelve">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+twelve+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>13:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="thirteen in planDay.progress.thirteen">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+thirteen+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>14:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="fourteen in planDay.progress.fourteen">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+fourteen+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>15:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="fifteen in planDay.progress.fifteen">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+fifteen+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0">
    <div>16:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="sixteen in planDay.progress.sixteen">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+sixteen+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0">
    <div>17:00</div>
    <div class="progress progress-plan">
      <template v-for="seventeen in planDay.progress.seventeen">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" :style="'width:'+seventeen+'%'" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Вот что получилось на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появилось несколько проблем:

1)Не учтена дата начала, на скрине это Элегант, дата начала с 12:20 до 12:30 - на шкале он не учитывает 12:20, отсчет начинает с начала и до 30

2)*Выделения на шкале используют 100 процентов, для выделения я использую минуты, максимальное значение в минутах это 60. Получается если будет например с 12:00 до 12:50, на шкале это будет 50% хотя 83%* Перевел минуты в проценты `(минуты*100)/60`

3)Если план будет с 12:00 до 13:00 все сломается

4)Как-то слишком много кода

Comment: nicolaa, вопрос слишком общий... Что именно не получается? Добавь пример кода, конкретики и опиши желаемый конечный результат

Comment: @Air Я еще не пробовал делать, интересует сама реализация, как это правильно сделать. Если делать 12 прогресс баров то я думаю что все получится сделать. Но будет ли это правильное решение? Может правильно это все сделать 1 прогресс баром или вообще делать не прогресс баром, а на div

Comment: nicolaa, программирование вещь неоднозначная. Методов реализации того или иного куча. Просто у тебя вопрос абстрактный... Для чего этот прогресс бар, какие данные ты собираешься получать. Что и для чего этот прогресс бар будут высчитывать. Добавь конкретики в вопрос.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @nicolaa «На bootstrap получилось сделать что-то подобное(Закинул на jsfiddle, внутри SO не работает)» Что там не так? я так и не понял.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev там рабочий пример, просто интересна правильная ли реализация, либо есть более простые способы сделать, может кто сталкивался

Comment: @nicolaa понятно. то решение, которое вам прислал, подходит (из другой темы)?

Answer (score 2):

Так как рабочих решений на html+css выдвинуто не было, предлагаю решение на canvas

```js
const time = {
  "11:00": [
    [0, 20],
    [40, 60]
  ],
  "12:00": [
    [10, 20],
    [30, 40],
    [50, 60]
  ],
  "13:00": [
    [0, 60]
  ],
  "14:00": [],
  "15:00": [],
  "16:00": [
    [25, 47]
  ]
};
window.addEventListener('resize', () => timeLine(time, "c"));
timeLine(time, "c")

function timeLine(time, canvasID) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const num = Object.keys(time).length;

  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eH3VCA/img-2018-11-22-18-03-12.png";
  img.onload = function() {
    const ptrn = c.createPattern(img, 'repeat'); // Create a pattern with this image, and set it to "repeat".

    c.canvas.width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).width);
    c.canvas.height = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).height);

    c.font = "10px Comic Sans MS";
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    c.strokeStyle = "black";



    const unitWidth = c.canvas.width / num;
    const tlh = c.canvas.height - 20; // tlh = timeline height

    let i = 0;
    for (let t in time) {
      if (time[t].length !== 0) {
        c.fillStyle = ptrn;
        time[t].forEach((it) => {
          c.fillRect(unitWidth * i + unitWidth / 60 * it[0], "0", unitWidth / 60 * (it[1] - it[0]), tlh);
        })
      }

      c.fillStyle = 'green';
      c.fillText(t, unitWidth * i, (2 * tlh + 20) / 2);
      i++;
    }

    //Draw vertical lines
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
      let x = unitWidth * i;
      // Check the first and last lines;
      x = x === 0 ? c.lineWidth / 2 : i === num ? (c.canvas.width - c.lineWidth / 2) : x;

      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(x, 0);
      c.lineTo(x, tlh);
      c.stroke();

    }
    // Top and bottom lines
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(c.lineWidth / 2, c.lineWidth / 2);
    c.lineTo(c.canvas.width, c.lineWidth / 2);

    c.moveTo(c.lineWidth, tlh - c.lineWidth / 2);
    c.lineTo(c.canvas.width, tlh - c.lineWidth / 2);
    c.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```